# GitLab Package Registry as Maven Artifactory

Tags: maven, dependencies, gitlab, repository, github-package-registry

I am trying to setup a GitLab project as the remote maven repository for all my other projects using GitLab Maven Package Registry. I have uploaded all dependency jar files to the package registry. All the jar files have been uploaded using maven's deploy feature. I am trying now to setup this project's package registry as the remote maven repository for all my other projects. The necessary repository settings is provided in the package registry itself, in each individual artifact page, as follows:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>gitlab-maven</id>
    <url>https://<gitlab_instance>/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/packages/maven</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>

<distributionManagement>
  <repository>
    <id>gitlab-maven</id>
    <url>https://<gitlab_instance>/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/packages/maven</url>
  </repository>

  <snapshotRepository>
    <id>gitlab-maven</id>
    <url>https://<gitlab_instance>/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/packages/maven</url>
  </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

However, even after adding this in the pom.xml of other projects, their builds are failing citing dependency unavailability. It seems that this project's package registry is unreachable from other projects. What am I doing wrong here? Are there any additional steps I need to undertake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you amend the settings.xml which you are using when calling a maven command?
There something like this:

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <configuration>
            <httpHeaders>
                <property>
                    <name>Job-Token</name>
                    <value>${env.CI_JOB_TOKEN}</value>
                </property>
            </httpHeaders>
        </configuration>
    </server>
</servers>
```

should be present. To use the settings.xml with your specific maven command, you can specify it by typing:

```
mvn -s settings.xml package
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an authenticate header(personal token, CI job token, or deploy token).

This is the doc: [Adding the GitLab Package Registry as a Maven remote](https://gitlab.com/help/user/packages/maven_repository/index.md#adding-the-gitlab-package-registry-as-a-maven-remote)